# How can I combine Wordpress Backend and my own front-end design without removing the current blogs and changing the upload system?

Tags: wordpress, frontend, backend, blogs

I can't find any  way to do so, I do not have constant access to the backend wordpress system however, I can get access for setup. I've designed and creating a responsive website using CSS HTML and JS for a blogging site but the people there aren't good at programming so updating the blog with new posts by simply editing code is hard for them, and I don't know backend development, how would I combine these two? Just updating the design of the website, I want the backend to stay intact.

I have tried making my own backend - but I'm not capable of making a easy to use system with all tools it needs,
I checked wordpress to see if they had any easy way to implement just the design however they didn't have anything.

Answer (score -1):

First, which design you have you just make a template of your design and then add to your website page with the help of **Elementor** page builder. Thank you

Comment: Not only is the wording of this answer unclear, but it’s also presumptuous: The original question makes no indication that the OP is using the Elementor page builder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).